# how to get data from mysql using oop..?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am getting data from data base using oop and it gives me data in array as

```
array(23) { 
   [0]=> array(6) { 
     [0]=> string(1) "6" 
     ["id"]=> string(1) "6" 
     [1]=> string(17) "Office Management" 
     ["Name"]=> string(17) "Office Management" 
     [2]=> string(1) "3" 
     ["top_parent_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
  }
}
```

when i try to ge data from array it gives error as

**"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\test.php on line 12"**

here is my code

```
    require_once('class.php');

$myClassObj = new db();

//$myClassObj->db();
$data = $myClassObj->select("parent_menu");
//var_dump($data);
foreach($data as $list)
{
    echo $list->{'0'}->id."<br>";
}
```

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($list)`

Answer (score 1):

`$data` is an `array` and you are trying to access values like an `object`. Try with -

```
echo $list[0]['id']."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see result. `$data` is object contain all data and `$list` is array. You can fetch data from list using index or key like

```
$list['id'];
$list[0];
```

both will work

Comment: it should be `$list[0]['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

`$list->{'0'}->id."<br>";` means you are try to access object of object

but you having array of array so try:-

```
echo $list[0]['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array(23) { 
   [0]=> array(6) { 
     [0]=> string(1) "6" 
     ["id"]=> string(1) "6" 
     [1]=> string(17) "Office Management" 
     ["Name"]=> string(17) "Office Management" 
     [2]=> string(1) "3" 
     ["top_parent_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
  }
  [1] => array(6) { 
     [0]=> string(1) "7" 
     ["id"]=> string(1) "7" 
     [1]=> string(17) "Office Management" 
     ["Name"]=> string(17) "Office Management" 
     [2]=> string(1) "3" 
     ["top_parent_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
  }
}
```

if the above data is the sample result of

```
$data =  $myClassObj->select("parent_menu");
```

then you are having a multidimensional array

since you are using a foreach

```
foreach($data as $list)
{
    // $list means you are accessing the index by index of
    // $data like $data[0], $data[1] until to the end of the
    // array
    // so list is an array already with properties
    // to access it

    $list['id'];
    $list['Name'];
    $list['top_parent_id'];

    // to add some error checking you can use
    // isset to check if property is existing to the array
    if (isset($list['id'])) {

    }
}
```